# Entity Framework Core 3 emulate PARTITION BY

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to retrieve the latest record for every group using EF Core 3 but every possible LINQ query I came up with ends up with the `InvalidOperationException` exception `Processing of the LINQ expression '...' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core`.

According to some answers that worked in EF Core 2.2 this query should did the trick but it didn't

```
from lfv in dbo.ListingFlagValues
group lfv by lfv.ListingId into groups
select groups.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault();
```

One more option I've tried was

```
db.ListingFlagValues.GroupBy(x => x.Listing)
  .Select(x => new { Group = x, MaxTimestamp = x.Max(y => y.Timestamp) })
  .SelectMany(x => x.Group.Select(y => new { y.ListingId, ValueId = y.NewFlagValueId, y.Timestamp, x.MaxTimestamp }))
  .Where(x => x.Timestamp == x.MaxTimestamp);
```

The behavior I'm trying to achieve is like in the following query

```
SELECT
    ListingId,
    NewFlagValueId AS ValueId
FROM
    (SELECT
        ListingFlagValues.ListingId,
        NewFlagValueId,
        [Timestamp],
        MAX([Timestamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY  ListingFlagValues.ListingId) AS MaxTimestamp
    FROM
        ListingFlagValues        
    WHERE 
        FlagId = 1) as FlagValues
WHERE [Timestamp] = [MaxTimestamp]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key here is *"This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core"* in the exception message (read *"may indicate"* as *"indicates*"). While EF Core 3.0 has improved the query translation, it still doesn't support many query patterns, especially on the result of `GroupBy`. And since it also removed client evaluation, queries which worked in 2.x because of silent client evaluation now are simply failing.

From the other side EF Core 3.0 has improved translation of the *last item in a group* pattern by utilizing the `ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY` SQL construct. However it doesn't work for `GroupBy` results, so you have to do the grouping manually by using `Distinct` query for keys and correlated subquery for values.

For instance, the following LINQ query

```
from listingId in db.ListingFlagValues.Select(x => x.ListingId).Distinct()
from lfv in db.ListingFlagValues
    .Where(x => x.ListingId == listingId)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Timestamp)
    .Take(1)
select lfv
```

translates and executes successfully using the following SQL

```sql
  SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[ListingId], [t1].[NewFlagValueId], [t1].[Timestamp]
  FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT [l].[ListingId]
      FROM [ListingFlagValues] AS [l]
  ) AS [t]
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[ListingId], [t0].[NewFlagValueId], [t0].[Timestamp]
      FROM (
          SELECT [l0].[Id], [l0].[ListingId], [l0].[NewFlagValueId], [l0].[Timestamp], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [l0].[ListingId] ORDER BY [l0].[Timestamp] DESC) AS [row]
          FROM [ListingFlagValues] AS [l0]
      ) AS [t0]
      WHERE [t0].[row] <= 1
  ) AS [t1] ON [t].[ListingId] = [t1].[ListingId]
```

Comment: Note: This also works for a LEFT JOIN, but if you're just selecting a few columns with a projection expression make sure to put `DefaultIfEmpty()` before `Take(1)` otherwise you'll end up selecting all the columns.